# Attempting to fix glitch bug in popular codepen infographic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fix a bug in this popular codepen infographic: http://codepen.io/shalabhvyas/pen/QbEbqd

If you click on any one of the icons and click on a different icon before the first one completed its animation, it will glitch.

So, I am trying to disable the ability to click while the infographic is rotating with something like:

```
document.addEventListener("click",handler,true);

function handler(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this to only disable clicking while the transform is happening and then allow clicking again once the transform is complete.

Once complete, I could just set to false:

```
  document.addEventListener("click",handler,false);
```

Sorry if this is too general, but take a look and maybe the implementation is simple. Thanks!

Comment: Not really in a position to dig through anything at the moment, but you could just cover it with an invisible div while the animation is going on. This wouldn't require major editing of your script. A bit of a patchwork solution, but it should work with little effort on your part.

Comment: Yeah, sort of felt bad asking the question, but it was bothering me and I was having trouble fixing it. That's a smart solution though. I'll try it out

Comment: @TaylorKirkpatrick Is right, that's a super cheap solution to the problem. To add to that suggestion (by way of specificity), to account for changes in the infographics size and shape I would give the div `opacity: 0;`, as Taylor said, and then set the `position: absolute;`, and then all of the positional parameters to 0, i.e. `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`...remembering to set the `.infographicWrapper { position: relative;` (since it will be the overlay div's parent).